# Given A family of disjoint closed intervals in [0,1], for any 0<=d<=1 can find x, x+d in this family, what's the minimal sum of length of intervals

Tags: combinatorics

Let S be the union of k disjoint, closed intervals in the unit interval [0, 1]. Suppose S has the property that for every real number $d$ with $0\leq d \leq 1$, there are two points in S at distance d. Prove that the sum of the lengths of the intervals in S is at least 1/k.

Please tell me if this question is duplicate. I searched for quite long time but didn't find a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try an answer.

Let $[a_i,b_i]$ $i=1,\cdots,k$ the intervals. For $A,B$ subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ put $A-B=\{c; \exists a\in A,b\in B; a-b=c\}$, hence  $S-S=\{t; \exists x,y\in S; t=x-y\}$. Your hypothesis imply that $[-1,1]\subset S-S$. Now we have $S-S\subset \cup_{i,j}([a_i,b_i]-[a_j,b_j])$. But $[a_i,b_i]-[a_j,b_j]\subset [a_i-b_j,b_i-a_j]$ and we get
$$[-1,1]\subset\cup_{i,j}[a_i-b_j,b_i-a_j ]$$

Hence $$2\leq \sum_{i,j}(b_i-a_i+b_j-a_j)=2k\sum_1^k(b_i-a_i)$$
and we are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I worked on this for several hours with no progress. The idea  is excellent, you're a genius!!!